# SQL query with two linked tables

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, inner-join

Please help to write this query. This is the table diagram:

[image: diagram]

User responds for selling drugs for specific sales types. How to find users that responds for same drugs in same sales type for specific user id?

For example:

- Alice respond for selling vitaminA, vitaminB in *retail*
- Bob respond for selling vitaminA, vitaminB in *retail* and *state market*
- Charlie respond for VitaminB, VitaminC in *state market*

Users that responds same salestype-drugs

- for Alice is Bob
- for Bob is Alice and Charlie
- for Charlie is Bob

Comment: Kindly rephrase your question.

Comment: SalesType-Drug is a key in the `User` table?

Comment: I don't think your data model supports your example... Specifically Bob is not possible because if you join the User Bob to vit A, Vit B, retail, state market you get all 4 combinations not just the 4 your proposed. You need a type that connects combinations of SalesType and Drug to a User (edit: in fact you *don't* need either of the bottom 2 tables you do currently have).

Comment: @CodeConfident - yes, I change example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For Given Example:

For the example data where users sell the same drugs through all sales types:

```
SELECT mus.userId 
FROM User2SalesType qus 
INNER JOIN User2Drug qud       ON qus.UserId = qud.UserId
INNER JOIN User2SalesType mus  ON qus.SalesTypeId = mus.SalesTypeId
                               AND mus.UserId != qus.UserId
INNER JOIN User2Drug mud       ON qud.DrugId = mud.DrugId 
                               AND mus.UserId = mud.UserId
WHERE qus.UserId = ? # querying user ID
```

---

## For More Flexible Data:

If you want to support a user selling drug A by sales X and drug B by sales Y (but not drug A by sales Y or drug B by sales X) you can use this data model:

```
User:       id, etc.
Response:   userId, salesTypeId, drugId
SalesType:  id, etc.
Drug:       id, etc.
```

Then you can query by self-joining Response:

```
SELECT mu.userId 
FROM response qu                       # querying user
INNER JOIN response mu                 # matching users
  ON qu.salesTypeId = mu.salesTypeId
  AND qu.drugId = mu.drugId
  AND qu.userId != mu.userId
WHERE qu.userId = ?                    # ? = querying user ID
```

Comment: you right, I change example. Changing model is not suitable

Comment: @user1167761 - I think my update works with your existing model.

Comment: thank you! Just add distinct - SELECT distinct(mus.userId)